# How do I overlay multiple graphics on one plot?

Tags: plotting, graphics, overlay

I am plotting n spectrum using:

```
  FileNameSetter[Dynamic[xx]]
  v = Table[Flatten[Import[ xx[[i]] ], 1], {i, 1, Length[xx]}];
  ListLinePlot[Table[v[[jj]], {jj, 1, Length[v]}], 
  PlotRange -> Full, AxesOrigin -> {0, 0}, PlotStyle -> Thick]
```

where `v[[jj]]` represens the data that I am plotting.

The problem with that approach is if `v[[1, x]] < v[[jj, x]]`, I cannot view the first spectrum.

Below is part of the result that I got. It has two graphics, but it is almost impossible to see the blue one.

I would like to overlay all the graphics in such a way that I can see all, like showed in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16262405/overlaying-two-graphs-using-viewports), but in an easier way, since I cannot understand `viewport` and all that.

Is there a simpler way to do this?

#### Edit

Here is an example of data:
[Spectrum1](https://mega.co.nz/#!9BdCjZJS!ruhK6uEhvu-67ZxQyHVdkVMLoCHoGytzLlI918WVRNA)
[Spectrum2](https://mega.co.nz/#!gQMxXDrZ!GGTM_qGYH9UrQvbdUKvqKGy8FMXNKAfU0nImbEmHswM)

I did some modifications in the code, so now it is more general:

```
  FileNameSetter[Dynamic[xx]]
  v = Table[Flatten[Import[ xx[[i]] ], 1], {i, 1, Length[xx]}];
  ww = {};
  color = {Blue, Red, Green, Black, White, Gray, Cyan, Magenta, Yellow, Brown, Orange, Pink, Purple};
  With[{opt = 
      Sequence[PlotRange -> {{500, 3000}, {0.9, 10000000}}, 
     ImagePadding -> 35, ImageSize -> 1000,
       BaseStyle -> {18, Bold}]},
    For[jk = 1, jk <= Length[v], jk++,
    If[jk != 1,
      ww = Join[
         ww, {ListLogPlot[v[[jk, 1000 ;;]], PlotStyle -> color[[jk]], Frame -> {{1, 0}, {1, 0}}, Joined -> True, opt]}],
      ww = Join[ww, {ListLogPlot[v[[jk, 1000 ;;]], PlotStyle -> color[[jk]], Frame -> {{1, 0}, {1, 0}}, Joined -> True, opt]}]
       ];
     ];
    Overlay[ww]
    ]
```

An advantage is that I can overlap 11 graphics together with the same scale (I put the scale but hand, but in principle it is easy to modify that).

I have still two problems:

1. I can't label the axes;
2. I can't put a legend without loosing the same scale for all graphics.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Hi, set the same `ImageSize/AspectRatio`, `ImagePadding` and use `Overlay`. Please let us know if you get stuck. Also, it is good to include the code you are working on, or at least minimal example of data.

Comment: Please post your the code you used to produce the image you posted along with the data sets it shows. That will make it easier for people to help you.

Comment: Thanks, @Kuba. Now I updated the code and put an example of data. I tried to use `Overlay` without success. It does the same as `Show`. I did not understand why to use `ImageSize/AspectRatio`, `ImagePadding`, it did nothing when I tried. Only with `Opacity` I got some result, but not the best.

Comment: If you set a precise `PlotRange` (not automatic or all) then there is no need to use Overlay. Try Show then.

Comment: All mode is not setting all with the same scale. With Show I did not get the same overlay. But at least now it is working, so I just need to improve it. ^^

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For the record.

The data you've provided do not match your plot. But here is the way:

```
dat1 = Import["Spectrum1.dat"]//Flatten;
dat2 = Import["Spectrum2.dat"]//Flatten;

With[{opt = Sequence[PlotRange -> All, ImagePadding -> 35, ImageSize -> 500, 
                     BaseStyle -> {18, Bold}]},
 Overlay[{
          ListLinePlot[dat1, PlotStyle -> Red, FrameStyle -> Red, 
                             Frame -> {{1, 0}, {1, 0}}, opt],
          ListLinePlot[dat2, Frame -> {{0, 1}, {0, 1}}, FrameStyle -> Blue,
                             FrameTicks -> {{None, All}, {None, All}}, opt]
   }]]
```

[image]

Or with `PlotRange -> Automatic`:

[image]

Comment: Thanks @Kuba. I did some modifications, so I can overlap N graphics, N<= 11. But I can't still write a legend automatically (when I do that they loose the common scale), and write a label (I put that information in the `opt` but it is simply not showing).

Comment: @Zhozer hard to guess, maybe `ImagePadding` is not big enough and label is just outside. Try bigger number.